# Typo3: How can i find my uploded extension which is listing in the typo3.org

Tags: typo3

I had uploaded my typo3 extension in the typo3.org-> [Extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/)

and it is listing under the specific category .But i can't find the same extension in the typo3 backend where we import the extension .Is it possible to import my extension from the backend of my typo3 site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need to retrive/update list of extensions in `Extenion Manager` on the target machine. Also remember also tht by default EM chooses random mirror, so if your extension was uploaded moments ago it can take some time to be available on each mirror.

On the other hand...

You don't need to publish it to TER if you want just share between many instances, just export it on the source machine to t3x file, and then import from the file. You can also just copy whole your extension folder from `typo3conf/ext` folder of source machine, to the same folder on the target machine, and than it will be in the identical state as it was downloaded from repo, but not installed yet.

Comment: @blesior:thank you.And one query Now all can download my extention from the typo3.org like that is it possible to import it from there the backend of typo3 site

Comment: Sorry... I don't get what you mean

Comment: i upload one extension in my TER and i can download directly from there .And my question is,did others can find my extension using there Extension Manager

Comment: If you can, others can also, it's public repository, what is its key ? I'll check it.

Comment: @blesior:titech_catalog is my extension key

Comment: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/titech_catalog as you can see it's available without problems (ver. 2.0.3), also in EM in backend it's available, of course it's required to update extensions list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26157/discussion-between-new-born-and-biesior)